# Yii2 sending email to gmail account via swift mailer

Tags: php, email, yii2, swiftmailer

I am trying to send email via swift mailer.I know there is a lot if similar questions but can't understand where is my problem. I did it just like i saw it in tutorial video in youtube (don't know shall i post the link here) but like always it is ok on the video but not on my project :D I tried with port 465 and encryption ssl also but without result. Will please you for some advice! Thank you in advance!

actionContact:

```
public function actionContact()
    {
        $model = new ContactForm();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->contact(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('contactFormSubmitted');

            return $this->refresh();
        }
        return $this->render('contact', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

mailer config:

```
'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'viewPath' => '@app/mail',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport' => false,
            'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
                'username' => 'tomaivanovtomov@gmail.com',
                'password' => 'password',
                'port' => '587',
                'encryption' => 'tls',
            ],
        ],
```

and params:

```
return [
    'adminEmail' => 'tomaivanovtomov@gmail.com',
];
```

I am pretty far from familiar with those emails things and i am still learning so please do not get mad at me for the pathetic question :)

**EDIT**:
ContactForm model:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

/**
 * ContactForm is the model behind the contact form.
 */
class ContactForm extends Model
{
    public $name;
    public $email;
    public $title;
    public $body;
    public $verifyCode;


    /**
     * @return array the validation rules.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // name, email, subject and body are required
            [['name', 'email', 'title', 'body'], 'required'],
            // email has to be a valid email address
            ['email', 'email'],
            // verifyCode needs to be entered correctly
            ['verifyCode', 'captcha'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'Name:',
            'email' => 'Email:',
            'title' => 'Title:',
            'body' => 'Connect with us :)',
            'verifyCode' => 'Verification Code'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Sends an email to the specified email address using the information collected by this model.
     * @param string $email the target email address
     * @return bool whether the model passes validation
     */
    public function contact($email)
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
                ->setTo($email)
                ->setFrom([$this->email => $this->name])
                ->setSubject($this->subject)
                ->setTextBody($this->body)
                ->send();

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Paste code that sends your emails via SwiftMailer.

Comment: Not sure what this code has to look like.

Comment: Like this one: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/frontend/models/ContactForm.php#L51

Comment: In the video i was watching they did not use it so i thought i don't need it to use a message->compose . But guess i am wrong :) I have to write that part in the actionContact right ?

Comment: Nope, your ContactForm model has "contact($email)" method as I see, so check what it do and fix if something is broken. Like here: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic/blob/master/models/ContactForm.php

Comment: Sure i got that one in the ContactForm but i thought it is basic thing in the yii2 templte that's why i did not mention it :) Edited now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wont boggle you with terms and code at the beginning.Just check whether security for less secure apps is OFF in your google account or not.If it is ON then turn it OFF.If all your settings are correct then this could be the unexpected glitch. Revert to me if that doesn't help. 
After adding the smtp configuration in config I used this to send my emails(also I don't remember adding any extra params to my config):

```
 $value=Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
->setFrom('tomaivanovtomov@gmail.com')
->setTo($model->emailAddress)
->setSubject($model->subject)
->setHtmlBody($model->content)
->attach($model->attachment)
->send();
```

where the emailAddress will be filled by various users when they fill out the form, if u have one.If that is not the case and you have the emails stored elsewhere then you will have to fetch them in a php variable and replace $model->emailAddress with that variable.

Comment: Yes, i turned it off in the beginning. But without success :)

Comment: I removed the `if(this->validate())` in the ContactForm and it is working so the problem is in the validation right ?

Comment: The problem now is that i am sending emails to the admin(me) from me only and not from the email i am typing in the contact form. I understood that this happens because of this line `'username' => 'tomaivanovtomov@gmail.com'`. How can i replace my email with the email of the user from the contact form ?

Comment: Yes I guess the problem was with validation.Coming to the next part of the problem.I  used the same feature but without any params. Check my edit.

Comment: Yes this is working :) Now you (in the role of admin) can send email to the users but i am searching for the opposite case. So users have to send emails to me through the form :) But now i am thinking it is not possible because they have to type their email-password otherwise guess gmail doesn't give them permission for sending an email. Not sure if i explained it well :)

Comment: I think i am in big confusion :) I want to send an email from my form to the admin but to do this i need to type the password of my email also.
Admin: tomaivanovtomov@gmail.com
Email i am typing int the form : user@gmail.com 
But i did not type the password of this email so it can't send nothing.

Comment: I am not sure about this but y don't you try inter changing just the set to and set from of the above code part and see if it still works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139454/discussion-between-toma-tomov-and-shikhar-singh).